# Possible to set wildcards in Turbine/eureka appconfig

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka, turbine

I am trying to set up turbine and eureka to work with some basic services. I am very much in the teething stage, so please be nice :D

I have it working with the following in my turbine config (note the appConfig line):

```
turbine:
    clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
    appConfig: service-a, service-b, service-c
    instanceUrlSuffix: /manage/hystrix.stream

InstanceDiscovery:
   impl: io.spring.platform.netflix.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery
```

This is all working good and well, but how things are planned to be set up, we will not necessarily know all the names of the services we will be exposing and displaying through Eureka.... So what I am looking for is a way to use wild cards in the appConfig list. For example, I would want something like:

```
turbine:
    clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
    appConfig: service-*
    instanceUrlSuffix: /manage/hystrix.stream

InstanceDiscovery:
   impl: io.spring.platform.netflix.turbine.EurekaInstanceDiscovery
```

where the * would match to any string... Unfortunately this doesn't work :( I found that nor does service.* or quoting either of those strings. Taking out the appConfig piece doesn't work either.

So is there anything that offers that functionality? I don't necessarily need to use wildcard string matching -- Even if there was some sort of default that matches to any service that is registered on Eureka would be perfect.

I have looked online for this sort of thing but don't know where to look/what to look for so I am hitting a dead end. My understanding is (correct me if I am wrong) that the EurekaInstanceDiscovery works by calling /eureka/apps and retrieving the XML info of services registered on Eureka. So I can't see why this notion would be impossible, but then I know very little about eureka/turbine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not possible at the moment. You can create an issue if you'd like.